# Windows WF 3.5 How to drop activity on Custom Composite Activity in Workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I have a custom activity which is a composite of several activities.  There are some activities on the composite where I would like users of the custom activity to be able to drop more activities at design time on the Worfkflow surface.

Custom **Composite** activities don't allow drag-drop actions out-of-the box, but I have tried using a custom designer and overridden OnDragDrop etc. and that did not work either.

Code samples/snippets in any answers would be most helpful...