# Windows Workflow Custom Sequence Activity

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I'm working with Windows Workflow 4, and I need to create a C# activity that, basically, inherits from the Sequence activity.  I want it to look just like the Sequence activity, so a user can drag and drop other activities onto it from the designer.  But, it acts differently in the code (maybe I want to run them in a different order, or do special actions between each one, it shouldn't matter).

How can I do this?  I see a [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208190/windows-wf-3-5-how-to-drop-activity-on-custom-composite-activity-in-workflow) about this, and only one person responded with a suggestion that only applies to Windows Workflow 3.  In version 4, a sequence activity can't be inherited from, to say the least.

This doesn't seem like a very far fetched concept.  A Sequence activity is provided as a built in activity. So, it seems logical that it should be reproducible, or at least inheritable, so I can have a customized version of a Sequence activity.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I ganked my version from MSDN:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar-SA/wfprerelease/thread/88464d23-21e8-4ace-9775-0260518da70d  required some modification and some reflection work to get everything working, but it looks as expected.

Comment: Will: that looks great, and this should be an answer.  But I am not sure how to implement it.  There's the "SpacerTemplate" UserControl, and when I paste this code into VS2010, it has several errors.  The class derives from IComponentConnector, but doesn't implement either of its methods.  And if I implement them with NotImplementedException() stubs, I get more errors: "this.dropTarget" doesn't exist, for instance. And the activity designer code (sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter), well, I can't figure out where to put that.  I'm new to workflows so I could really use a more idiot proof example.

Comment: Ooo! Ooo! Okay, I had to change the namespace in the SpacerTemplate XAML to match the Code's namespace.  Duh! That fixes the interface implementation issue (well, it compiles).  Now I gotta figure out how to create that designer. I don't know where to put that sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter block of XAML.

Comment: Your IComponentConnector issue is caused by copypasting code from the internets.  This is a programming sin, and you must repent by NOT copypasting codes but by creating a new UserControl and using the example code as a GUIDE.  Your issues have nothing to do with WF, they are all WPF.  Slow down and understand what you are doing before doing it.

Comment: I'm now at the point where I have an activity that says "Add an 'XXX' activity" and won't accept drag and drops.  I promise you, I'm trying hard to understand what I'm doing, but I don't. If I slowed down anymore, I'd be going backwards.

Comment: Okay, the book "Microsoft Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 Cookbook" includes a composite activity called "MySequence" sample starting page 161. I'll look into that, and read it very carefully :)

Comment: That's usually a problem with the binding.  Start small, then go big.

Comment: Yep, had the wrong collection variable name.  Now I think it's working, but the animation doesn't look exactly like Sequence, it just draws a gray bar overlapping the arrow, and doesn't change the height of the activity like Sequence does.

Comment: You either have to tweak it yourself, or disassemble the baml of the designer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "System.Activities.Core.Presentation.SequenceDesigner" designer is already available in WF 4.  One can then compose a Sequence activity and use this designer for the outer class.

Here's a working example:

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

[Designer("System.Activities.Core.Presentation.SequenceDesigner, System.Activities.Core.Presentation")]
public class MySeq : NativeActivity
{
    private Sequence innerSequence = new Sequence();

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Collection<Activity> Activities
    {
        get
        {
            return innerSequence.Activities;
        }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public Collection<Variable> Variables
    {
        get
        {
            return innerSequence.Variables;
        }
    }

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddImplementationChild(innerSequence);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(innerSequence);
    }

}
```

This is forwarding the real behavior on to a private innerSequence, which might make this code seem useless, but note that in the Execute method it gives us a chance to do things before and after execution.  If we want to provide customized behavior, we'd have to implement it instead of forwarding to an inner private activity.

Comment: Can this accept Arguments? In my scenario I need to have a Sequence which contains multiple custom activities. When I try to pass Argument, it is saying there is no mapping.

Comment: Is there any update on passing arguments through to custom activities?

Comment: I know this is seriously old but I thought I'd chance it but I tried using the above code but I'm getting error with "[Designer("System.Activities.Core.Presentation.SequenceDesigner, System.Activities.Core.Presentation")]
p" as it's not finding it. I've had a look at the MS Source code on git but it does not appear to have SeqenceDesigner in System.Activities.Core.Presentation. I literarily want to mimic the exact UI of the sequence but I just need to expand its functionality a bit.  Any ideas on how to fix this or is there another way to go about it? Thanks.