# Builtin DropActivityHere Designer?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've noticed the System.Activities.Core.Presentation assembly contains several designers, and I've found them to be quite [useful for re-usability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521696/windows-workflow-custom-sequence-activity).

I've now found myself creating activities that need to say "*Drop activity here*" (they accept a child activity).  This is seen all over the place with the built-in WF activities, so I assume there must be some designer, e.g., DropHereDesigner, somewhere.  I can reproduce it with XAML, but I don't want to unless I must.

Anyone know if this designer can be found anywhere in the WF built-in libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [WorkflowItemPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.workflowitempresenter.aspx) is used for this functionality.

```
<WorkflowItemPresenter
    xmlns="clrnamespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
    HintText="Drop activity here"
    Item="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Child.Handler}" />
```

However, if you are asking "Can I get away with not touching XAML in order to create a designer" the answer is amost assuredly **no**.