# Is the designer source code for Windows Workflow Sequence activity available for reference?

Tags: c#, workflow

Re-sharper is able to find the source code for the Sequence activity itself from Workflow. In looking around the System.Activities dll my project references I don't see how the designer is linked. I was expected to have found somewhere a reference to AttributeTableBuilder with a call to the AddCustomAttributes like is done for an activity with a custom designer.

Is the designer source code for the Sequence activity designer available somewhere on the internet? I was hoping to take a look at it to learn how Microsoft designed the Sequence UI. I tried googling it, but was only finding information about building a custom activity designer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same as built-in Sequence Activity, Custom Activity is  the correct choice, and you should use WorkflowItemsPresenter, this example will show result as built-in Sequence Activity:
 activity designer xaml:

```
<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="ProjectForm2.ActivityDesigner1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:sap="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation"
xmlns:sapv="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Presentation.View;assembly=System.Activities.Presentation">
<sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
     <Style x:Key="WorkflowItemsPresenterStyle" TargetType="sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter">
            <Setter Property="SpacerTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Transparent">
                            <Path Data="F1M181.297,177.841L181.205,177.746 181.385,177.563 202.804,156.146 202.804,135.07 178.497,159.373 170.847,167.026 170.666,167.205 163.107,159.653 138.804,135.345 138.804,156.42 160.219,177.841 170.76,188.379 181.297,177.841z" 
                      Stretch="Uniform" Fill="#FFDEDDDD" 
                      Width="15" Height="15" Margin="0,0,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                        </Border>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                        <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</sap:ActivityDesigner.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>

    </Grid.Resources>
    <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter Style="{StaticResource WorkflowItemsPresenterStyle}" AllowDrop="True"   Items="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Activities}"  HintText="Insert here">

    </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter>
</Grid>
```

Activity class:

```
  [Designer(typeof(ActivityDesigner1))]
  public sealed class CodeActivity1 : CodeActivity
{
    public CodeActivity1()
    {
          Activities = new List<Activity>();
        Activities.Add(new Assign());
        Activities.Add(new Assign());
    }
   public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your sample XAML. It was close, but not quite the same as the real thing. I played with it and did make one change to make the separator icon more like the real thing:

  <sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
              <Polygon Stretch="Uniform" Width="15" Height="15"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       Points="0,0 7,10, 14,0" Stroke="Black" Fill="{x:Null}" StrokeThickness="0.3" Margin="0,10,0,15"  />
          </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
  </sap:WorkflowItemsPresenter.SpacerTemplate>

Answer (score 0):

The designer exists in the System.Activities.Core.Presentation.dll which if you add it to the project you use can use Re-Sharper to browse to: 
System.Activities.Core.Presentation.SequenceDesigner

The designer is mapped with a AtributeTableBuilder in the DesignerMetadata class:
System.Activities.Core.Presentation.DesignerMetadata

You can also see the c# code at: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Activities.Core.Presentation/System/Activities/Core/Presentation/SequenceDesigner.xaml.cs

One interesting approach I found afterwards is you can directly use the sequence's designer as outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521696/windows-workflow-custom-sequence-activity?rq=1).

I still have not found the actual XAML....It would be interesting to see the real thing.