# Passing variable through context.ScheduleActivity() in custom WPF component

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, workflow-foundation, uipath

I have created an activity to mimic the sequence activity in WPF using the below code with help from [Windows Workflow Custom Sequence Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521696/windows-workflow-custom-sequence-activity)

```
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Custom_Activities
{
    [Designer("System.Activities.Core.Presentation.SequenceDesigner, System.Activities.Core.Presentation")]
    public class Scoped_Activity_Scope : NativeActivity
    {
        private string TestVariable = "testing testing";
        private Sequence innerSequence = new Sequence();

        [Browsable(false)]
        public Collection<Activity> Activities
        {
            get 
            {
                return innerSequence.Activities;
            }
        }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public Collection<Variable> Variables
        {
            get
            {
                return innerSequence.Variables;
            }
        }

        protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
        {
            metadata.AddImplementationChild(innerSequence);
        }

        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Scope Executing");
            context.ScheduleActivity(innerSequence);
        }

    }
}
```

I also have created a second custom activity below

```
using System.Activities;

namespace Custom_Activities
{
    public sealed class Scoped_Activity : Scoped_Activity_Template
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Scope Activity Executing");
            //System.Console.WriteLine(testVariable);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code as below

[image]

I get the desired output

`Scope Executing`

`Scope Activity Executing`

How can I pass the variable `testVariable` from the class `Scoped_Activity_Scope` for use within `Scoped_Activity` as per the line of code commented out?

Comment: You dont need to pass the variable, In the parent class `Scoped_Activity_Scope` just make the variable public. You will be able to access the variable in the child class `Scoped_Activity`

Comment: @Aakanksha `Scope_Activity_Scope` isn't the parent activity of `Scoped_Activity` so I'm not sure if that would work, I'm just testing it now

Comment: @Aakanksha getting the error Getting the following error 
`##[error]Custom_Activities\Scoped_Activity.cs(13,38): Error CS0103: The name 'TestVariable' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Then how is `Scoped_Activity` and`Scope_Activity_Scope` related?

Comment: `Scoped_Activity` is executed from within the `innerSequence` in `Scoped_Activity_Scope`. One object executing another, there is no inheritance/implementation between the 2 classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Scoped_Activity_Scope` within the `Execute` method I added the following code to iterate through the activities within `innerSequence`

```
foreach(Activity a in innerSequence.Activities)
{
    if (a.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(UiPath_Activities_Templates.Scoped_Activity_Template)))
    {
        Scoped_Activity_Template vet = null;
        vet = (Scoped_Activity_Template) a;
        vet.UpdateTestVariable("changed");
    }
}
```

And in the class 'Scoped_Activity_Template' which 'Scoped_Activity' inherits from (this class was previously empty) I added the following code

```
public static string TestVariable = "testing";

public void UpdateTestVariable(string newValue)
{
    TestVariable = newValue;
}
```

That way the inherited class `Scoped_Activity` has access to the variable `TestVariable`.

When the loop iterates over the activities in `innerSequence` it checks if it inherits from `Scoped_Activity_Template` it calls the method `UpdateTestVariable` to update the variable.

When the class `Scoped_Activity` is then executed it will have the updated variable.

Answer (score 1):

First you create a property for the inner activity:

```
public string TestVariable { get; set; }
```

Then you can access that property through the `Activities` collection.

There are 2 situations where you need to update the value of `TestVariable`: 1, When `TestVariable` changes, and 2, When you add a new `Scoped_Activity` to `Scoped_Activity_Scope`.

Number 1 is easy, just change all `Scoped_Activity.TestVariable`s every time you change the parent's `TestVariable`. Number 2 is a little more difficult. You need to be able to catch the `CollectionChanged` event which is fired every time you change `Activities` from the UI. This is possible through the designer of the activity. I assume you have probably written a custom designer for the activity.

```
public Scoped_Activity_Scope_Designer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += AddCollectionChangedHandler;
}

private void AddCollectionChangedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ownactivities = 
        ModelItem.Properties[nameof(Scoped_Activity_Scope.Activities)].Collection;
    ownactivities.CollectionChanged += AddTestVariable;
}
```

Inside `AddTestVariable`, just update the `TestVariable` property of every activity in `ownActivities`, which you need to retrieve again.

---

As an aside, you can also access `TestVariable` by calling the Parent, but then again, you still need to do it inside of `Scoped_Activity_Designer`, which is the one that actually has access to the parent. However, `Scoped_Activity_Designer` doesn't know when `TestVariable` has been updated, and it doesn't know when execute is called in order to retrieve the most up to date value. Using `CollectionChanged` is probably the best way to do it.

This is how you access `TestVariable` through the parent:

```
var dataContext = 
    Parent.GetValue(Scoped_Activity_Scope_Designer.DataContextProperty);
if (dataContext != null)
{
    var designer = (Scoped_Activity_Scope_Designer) dataContext;
    var scoped_activity_scope = (Scoped_Activity_Scope) designer.ModelItem.GetCurrentValue();
    var scoped_activity = (Scoped_Activity) ModelItem.GetCurrentValue();
    scoped_activity.TestVariable = scoped_activity_scope.TestVariable;
}
```

You should put this code in the handler for the Loaded event inside `Scoped_Activity_Designer`.

Comment: so for the situations you mentioned I'm not looking to implement handling changes to the variable. I want to define a static variable that won't change and pass it to all of the activities within the `innerSequence`.
How would I access this variable from within `Scoped_Activity`?

Comment: @Conor I have updated the answer to show how to do get the variable once through Parent. You cannot do it from inside ```Scoped_Activity``` however. It needs to be done inside the designer. The designer is the one who has access to both the parent and child activities.

Comment: But if i had say `Scoped_Activity1`, `Scoped_Activity2` and `Scoped_Activity3` and i want to make the variable available to all of them would I have to repeat this code for all of the activities

Comment: Then use ```CollectionChanged```. You can update all children activities that way. Just write an interface that says you have to have ```TestVariable``` and implement that interface for every activity that needs to retrieve ```TestVariable```.

Comment: Ahh, just read through the code again, I am using a predesigned Designer not a custom designer so I'm not sure how I would implement the code as I dont have a designer file